# Springboot 3 : JPQL to SQL translation, wrong column selection using "select new" and "right join"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

When migrating from springboot 2.7 to springboot 3.1 my generated sql queries from jpql are wrongs.
Inpacted queries are those with "select new" and "right join" : I use this to create a projection called MyProjection from two entities E & C.
I need projection even if entity C is non existant.
I need id of the E entity every time in my projection.

With springboot 2.7 it works (it works for a long time and with anterior springboot versions).
But with springboot 3.1 I encounter a problem : the select always use the entity C forein key to E instead of the id of the E entity.
So, when C is null, the id of the E entity is null in my projection.

Is this a bug ? Or something else ?

Exemple :
**Entity C**

```
@Entity
public class EntityC implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String reference;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_e_id")
  private EntityE entityE;


}
```

**Entity E**

```
@Entity
public class EntityE implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;


}
```

**My Projection**

```
public class MyProjection implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3431863476946276142L;

  private Long entityEId;
  private Long entityCId;

  private String entityEName;
  private String entityCReference;

  public MyProjection(
      Long entityEId,
      Long entityCId,
      String entityEName,
      String entityCReference) {
    this.entityEId = entityEId;
    this.entityCId = entityCId;
    this.entityEName = entityEName;
    this.entityCReference = entityCReference;
  }
  
  public MyProjection(
      Long entityEId,
      Long entityCId) {
    this.entityEId = entityCId;
    this.entityEId = entityCId;
  }

  
  public MyProjection() {}
  
}
```

**Queries**
JPQL Query

```
select new MyProjection(e.id, c.id, e.name, c.reference)
from EntityC c right join c.entityE e;
```

Springboot 2.7.x Generated SQL

```
select e1_.id as col_0_0_, c0_.id as col_1_0_, e1_.name as col_2_0_, c0_.reference as col_3_0_
from entity_c c0_ 
right outer join entity_e e1_ on c0_.entity_e_id=e1_.id;
```

Springboot 3.1.x Generated SQL

```
select c0_.entity_e_id as col_0_0_, c0_.id as col_1_0_, e1_.name as col_2_0_, c0_.reference as col_3_0_
from entity_c c0_ 
right join entity_e e1_ on c0_.entity_e_id=e1_.id;
```

I tried springboot 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT, I tried to downgrade hibernate to 5.x but downgrading failed.